# Is reddit blocking Tails?

Tags: tails

Yesterday I was runnig Tails and obviously using tor.
The point is that some subreddits doesn't allowed me to access, showing a 503 message. After a moment, the message appeared in general. Right now using tor on Debian, I'd tried to open the same posts and everything just worked fine.
I found this guy experiencing something similar

https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/kvet7t/reddit_is_blocking_me/

So the question is  Why this is happening? I thought tor is the same for Tails, Debian or whatever distro you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also happens to me running Tor Browser 10.0.8 for Linux. I don't know why this is happening, but I have figured out a workaround: change the URL from https://**www**.reddit.com/r/... to https://**old**.reddit.com/r/...

Doing this allows me to access any of the pages on which I previously received a 503 error. Hopefully it works for you